# Spark Scala: moving average for multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Input:**

```
val customers = sc.parallelize(List(("Alice", "2016-05-01", 50.00,4),
                                ("Alice", "2016-05-03", 45.00,2),
                                ("Alice", "2016-05-04", 55.00,4),
                                ("Bob", "2016-05-01", 25.00,6),
                                ("Bob", "2016-05-04", 29.00,7),
                                ("Bob", "2016-05-06", 27.00,10))).
                           toDF("name", "date", "amountSpent","NumItems")
```

**Procedure:**

```
 // Import the window functions.
 import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 // Create a window spec.
 val wSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(-1, 1)
```

In this window spec, the data is partitioned by customer. Each customer’s data is ordered by date. And, the window frame is defined as starting from -1 (one row before the current row) and ending at 1 (one row after the current row), for a total of 3 rows in the sliding window. **The problem is to take window-based summation for a list of columns**. In this case, they're "amountSpent","NumItems". But the problem can have up to hundreds of columns.

Below is the solution for doing window-based summation for each column. However, **how to perform the summation more effectively?** because we don't need to do find slided-window rows every time for each column.

```
 // Calculate the sum of spent
 customers.withColumn("sumSpent",sum(customers("amountSpent")).over(wSpec1)).show()

  +-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
  | name|      date|amountSpent|NumItems|sumSpent|
  +-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
  |Alice|2016-05-01|       50.0|       4|    95.0|
  |Alice|2016-05-03|       45.0|       2|   150.0|
  |Alice|2016-05-04|       55.0|       4|   100.0|
  |  Bob|2016-05-01|       25.0|       6|    54.0|
  |  Bob|2016-05-04|       29.0|       7|    81.0|
  |  Bob|2016-05-06|       27.0|      10|    56.0|
  +-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+

 // Calculate the sum of items
 customers.withColumn( "sumItems",
                sum(customers("NumItems")).over(wSpec1)  ).show()

  +-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
  | name|      date|amountSpent|NumItems|sumItems|
  +-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
  |Alice|2016-05-01|       50.0|       4|       6|
  |Alice|2016-05-03|       45.0|       2|      10|
  |Alice|2016-05-04|       55.0|       4|       6|
  |  Bob|2016-05-01|       25.0|       6|      13|
  |  Bob|2016-05-04|       29.0|       7|      23|
  |  Bob|2016-05-06|       27.0|      10|      17|
  +-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: do you need a separate column for each moving sum?

Comment: all the summarized columns can be in a separate dataframe.

Comment: @HappyCoding If an answer helps you please upvote/accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, I guess, its not possible to update multiple columns using Window function. You can act as if its happening at the same time as below

```
val customers = sc.parallelize(List(("Alice", "2016-05-01", 50.00,4),
  ("Alice", "2016-05-03", 45.00,2),
  ("Alice", "2016-05-04", 55.00,4),
  ("Bob", "2016-05-01", 25.00,6),
  ("Bob", "2016-05-04", 29.00,7),
  ("Bob", "2016-05-06", 27.00,10))).
  toDF("name", "date", "amountSpent","NumItems")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Create a window spec.
val wSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(-1, 1)
var tempdf = customers
val colNames = List("amountSpent", "NumItems")
for(column <- colNames){
  tempdf = tempdf.withColumn(column+"Sum", sum(tempdf(column)).over(wSpec1))
}
tempdf.show(false)
```

You should have output as

```
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+
|name |date      |amountSpent|NumItems|amountSpentSum|NumItemsSum|
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+
|Bob  |2016-05-01|25.0       |6       |54.0          |13         |
|Bob  |2016-05-04|29.0       |7       |81.0          |23         |
|Bob  |2016-05-06|27.0       |10      |56.0          |17         |
|Alice|2016-05-01|50.0       |4       |95.0          |6          |
|Alice|2016-05-03|45.0       |2       |150.0         |10         |
|Alice|2016-05-04|55.0       |4       |100.0         |6          |
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to calculate the window only once (if you have Spark 2 which allows you to use `collect_list` with struct-types), assuming the to have the dataframe and windowSpec as in your code, then:

```
val colNames = List("amountSpent","NumItems")
val cols= colNames.map(col(_))

// put window-content of all columns in one struct
val df_wc_arr = customers
.withColumn("window_content_arr",collect_list(struct(cols:_*)).over(wSpec1))

// calculate sum of window-content for each column
// aggregation exression used later
val aggExpr = colNames.map(n => sum(col("window_content."+n)).as(n+"Sum"))

df_wc_arr
.withColumn("window_content",explode($"window_content_arr"))
.drop($"window_content_arr")
.groupBy(($"name" :: $"date" :: cols):_*)
.agg(aggExpr.head,aggExpr.tail:_*)
.orderBy($"name",$"date")
.show
```

gives

```
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+
| name|      date|amountSpent|NumItems|amountSpentSum|NumItemsSum|
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+
|Alice|2016-05-01|       50.0|       4|          95.0|          6|
|Alice|2016-05-03|       45.0|       2|         150.0|         10|
|Alice|2016-05-04|       55.0|       4|         100.0|          6|
|  Bob|2016-05-01|       25.0|       6|          54.0|         13|
|  Bob|2016-05-04|       29.0|       7|          81.0|         23|
|  Bob|2016-05-06|       27.0|      10|          56.0|         17|
+-----+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+
```